# how to use php foreach loop with javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, foreach, codeigniter-3

I want to get data from foreach loop to variable of javascript ? Then I try some method to get and it work but it not going to separate array it's go as a one value. Can someone help me ??

Here is my code:

```
<script>
<?php $var = array('array1','array2'); ?>
var x = ['<?php foreach($var as $data){ echo $data } ?>'];
</script>
```

Then it return me: `['array1array2`]

In this I want show me like this:

```
['array1', 'array2'];
```

thank for your help !!!

Comment: try using json_encode() function to convert ur array to json and then convert it back to array from ur javascript code

Comment: <script>
    var x = <?php echo json_encode(array('array1','array2')); ?>;
</script>

Comment: can you show me if I want it with foreach loop ?

Comment: @SopheakRotanak why do you need a loop, json_encode also works with arrays you don't have to do it yourself. `var x = <?= json_encode($var); ?>;`